# Sprite animation using multiple pngs

Tags: animation, svg, cross-platform, sprite, spritely

I've been trying to do a little cross-platform animation, thus no web-kit frames or canvas etc, no svg(Android issue) either

I have 7 pngs and I want to animate through them(not using bunch of setTimeOuts), this sounds to me like a very simply problem, but I could not find a solution after quite some Googling.

things I've looked at include sprite.js, spritely and etc, but I really do not want to combine all my 7 frames into a single sprite

is there a lite animation library that allows me to easily animate thought 7 separate pngs cross-platformly?

Comment: The reason why libraries are expecting you to have a combined sprite sheet is because this is the right way to do it. Changing `background-position` is more efficient than toggling visibility, and less requests are made to the server. I'd recommend combining the frames.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the best way, but i have AnimationTime variable that I increment on every loop. and when that varialbe reach some number then i increase frame of image and reset AnimationTime back to 0.

pseudo code

```
AnimationDuraion = 10;
do
AnimationTime += 1;
if (AnimationTime == AnimationDuration){AnimationTime = 0; SpriteFrame +=1;}
if (SpriteFrame > MaxSpriteFrames) {SpriteFrame = 0}
loop
```

and depend on SpriteFrame show that frame changing "background-position" as Duopixel suggested.